# Can I use Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web or 2010 for personal use at home?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Can I use Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web or 2010 for personal use at home? I'm new to web development and I do not have any paid or student copies of visual studio or anything.

I am curious if i can use these because I noticed that after 30 days it prompts you to register the product. In that registration it asks you for your business your title at work, work phone, and so on.

I don't plan on selling my software, but I might. Would this be permissible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the 'express' version of a Microsoft development tool, you are completely free to use it at home for personal use, yes.  That's kind of the point of their Express edition toolset.

Comment: ok well thats good to know, Im just curious as to why it requires business address, name, phone, position, and so on. And with the express version am i allowed to publish my site on the web as well?

Comment: Yes, you can publish your site on the web.  And you would be able to charge for your products as well, I believe.  However I am looking right now for the supporting official documentation links; I will post them if I find them.

Comment: Alright Thank you i looked but couldn't find anything but if you do thanks!

Comment: Here is a response on Microsoft's MSDN forums, stating you can use at least the 2010 Express editions and I highly doubt they changed it for 2012.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/3952ef19-86e6-4e60-9450-bf7717f5f598/

Comment: should i just use my home address and what not to register then lol

Comment: @squinny yes, exactly, home address & write "personal use" or something in business name.

Comment: arite thanks guys i appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The popular consensus across the internet states that you can use express for personal and commercial use.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/1aaf1efc-04df-40b9-9289-f3db0420c206